# What is the largest bet that cannot be made with $7$ and $9$ dollar chips? (Frobenius number)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question as posed is: What is the largest bet that cannot be made with chips worth $7.00$ and $9.00?$ To prove my conjecture, I am supposed to use both forms of induction.

After research, I found this quantity to be the Frobenius number, $g(a_1,a_2),$ if $\gcd(a_1,a_2)=1$. Through experimentation, or a formula, one finds this 'largest' bet to $47.$

Thus our problem can be stated as follows:

Show that every integer $n\geq48$ can be written $$n=7a+9b$$
for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^+\cup\{0\}$.

My attempt via induction:

Let $S:=\{7a+9b:7a+9b\geq48\text{ and }\ a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^+\cup\{0\}\}$. First, we confirm that $48\in S$. Take $a=3$ and $b=3$ to see $48\in S$.

Now assume for some $n>48 $ that it can be written $$n=7a+9b$$ for positive  (or zero) integers and thus $n\in S$. We need to show $n+1\in S.$  Thus $$n=7a+9b\in S\implies$$ $$n+1=7a+9b+1=7a+9b+4(7)-3(9)=7(a+4)+9(b-3)\in S$$

But here is where I get confused. In the book the author justifies confusingly that $a+4$ and $b-3$ are always positive (or zero) integers, and argues that this process shows you can always bet $1$ dollar more by adding four $7$ dollar chips and simultaneously taking away three $9$ dollar chips, but how can we always be sure there's enough $9$ dollar chips to take away, or, how can we be sure $a+4$ and $b-3$ are always positive?

I'm not sure about the strong induction case either.

Here is the process I'm trying to reproduce [image]

The part I am failing to understand and rigorously accept is from the paragraph "Let S be..." and down.

Comment: The first proof is explained in answers in the linked dupe (e.g. hmakhom's and mine). The second proof lifts the representations of the $\color{#c00}5$ base case integers $\,28,29,\ldots 32\,$ up to all greater integers by simply $\,\color{#0a0}{{\rm incrementing}\ x}$ to add $\,\color{#c00}5\,$ i.e. $\,5x+8y = n\,\Rightarrow\, 5(\color{#0a0}{x\!+\!1})+8y = n+\color{#c00}5.\,$ So doing this once to our base $5$ integers yields reps for $\,5+\{28,29,\ldots 32\} = 33,34,\ldots,37,\,$ and continuing this inductively yields reps for all larger integers.

Comment: If you have further questions please post comments either here or there.

Comment: Oops,  I meant to refer to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8186/when-do-the-multiples-of-two-primes-span-all-large-enough-natural-numbers) for the first proof (dupe list now updated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that justifying we can have $b\ge3$ is not obvious. In fact the argument would seem to have $b$ decreasing by $3$ on each induction step. The justification is that supposedly it's obvious that you can always have $b\ge3$ though... I honestly don't have any intuitive explanation why on this part.

---

In my opinion though, the strong induction proof is much nicer.

Assume we have $\{n,n+1,n+2,n+3,n+4,n+5,n+6\}\subseteq S$.

One can then easily verify that $\{n+1,n+2,n+3,n+4,n+5,n+6,n+7\}\subseteq S$ by adding $7$ to $n$.

By induction, $\{n,n+1,n+2,n+3,n+4,n+5,n+6\}\subseteq S$ for any $n\ge48$. As an immediate consequence, $n\in S$ for any $n\ge48$.

Note that this procedure requires the stronger base case of $\{48,49,50,51,52,53,54\}\subseteq S$, but now avoids fiddling with the coefficients.

---

In fact, the strong induction follows more obviously from [how the Frobenius number can be found](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3505637/272831), which is more reason to proving it in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different way of looking at this.

We can make any multiple of $7$

With one $9$ we can make any positive integer equivalent to $2$ modulo $7$ provided it is at least $9$

With two nines we get all $\equiv 4 \bmod 7$ provided they are at least $18$

With three nines we get $\equiv 6$ provided at least $27$

Four nines gives $\equiv 1$ provided at least $36$

Five nines gives $\equiv 3$ provided at least $45$

Six nines gives $\equiv 5$ provided at least $54$

This covers all the equivalence classes modulo $7$ and the last number you can't do is $54-7=47$ - the largest in the equivalence class of $5$ which can't be done.

This argument can be adapted to give a general result - if the two numbers have no factor in common you can exhaust the equivalence classes in this way.

---

For your example, and your method, suppose you have a total $\ge 48$ and fewer than three $9s$ then you have at least $30=48-18$ made up of sevens and therefore have at least four sevens in the total.

On the other hand if you have fewer than four sevens you have at least $48-21=27$ made up of nines and therefore at least three nines in the total.